# How to change the location of a shared JRE in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I want to share the JRE of my main application with add-ons which will be installed using a separate installer. Main application an add-ons belong to the same product line. The JRE should be shared among all products of this line but not with other products.

Is it possible to define the path of the shared JRE instead of using "...\common files\i4j_jres"?

I'd like to use something like

"...\common files\my company\product line1\jre"
and 
"...\common files\my company\product line2\jre"

Answer (score 0):

The installation directory for shared JREs cannot be customized.

If you use add-on installers (Installer->Update Options), they will pick up the JRE of the main product automatically. In that case you don't set to select "Install as a shared JRE bundle" in the media wizard. The add-ons cannot have a separate installation directory in that case and they cannot be uninstalled separately.

Another option is to set an environment variable with a "Modify an environment variable on Windows" action and a value of `${installer:sys.preferredJre}`. In the installers for your add-on products, add a corresponding environment variable entry to the Java search sequence (General Settings->Java version).

Comment: The updates/add-ons which could be deployed by Update Options are not sufficient for "real" add-ons: They can't be uninstalled and the name of the main installation is overwritten.
Creating an environment variable seems to be unstable. Is it possible to find the already installed main program and use it's private JRE for a separately installed add-on?

Comment: No, that's currently not possible. I've added it to our issue tracker.